# How do I replace an HTML button with several images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, button

I currently have:

```
//javascript
function morshots()
{
    var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
    var shots= (
    mordor.innerHTML = <img src="http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png" alt="scrns1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png" alt="scrns2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png" alt="scrns3">;
}
```

and

```
<!--html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="screenshots.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ss1">
            <button onClick="morshots();">View Screenshots</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently the button does nothing on click. What I want is for the images to replace the button on the page. This is not my entire code, however I omitted the non-pertinent piece of code for readability.

--EDIT--

I have added escapes for the inner quotes and non-escaped quotes around the image tags. I am still getting the same result with the page (button click does nothing)

```
function morshots()
{
var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
mordor.innerHTML = '<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png\" alt=\"scrns1\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png\" alt=\"scrns2\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png\" alt=\"scrns3\">';
}'
```

---EDIT2:----

Fixed it, the working code reads:

```
function morshots()
{var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
mordor.innerHTML = '<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png\" alt=\"scrns1\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png\" alt=\"scrns2\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png\" alt=\"scrns3\">';
}
```

Comment: You're missing quotation marks around the `img` tags

Comment: How does that JS even work? you're missing quotation marks on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<img>`s within quotes:

```
function morshots()
{
    var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
    mordor.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png" alt="scrns1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png" alt="scrns2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png" alt="scrns3">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your JavaScript console for errors?

```
// syntax error:
var shots= (

// syntax error:
mordor.innerHTML = <img src="http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png" alt="scrns1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png" alt="scrns2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png" alt="scrns3">;
```

You need to pass a string to `mordor.innerHTML` - wrap your html in quotes.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `shots`.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes and escape them withing html adding backslash \ before them:

```
var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
mordor.onclick = function () {
  var shots= "<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png\" alt=\"scrns1\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png\" alt=\"scrns2\"><img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png\" alt=\"scrns3\">";
  mordor.innerHTML = shots;
};
```